# Prevent Highcharts labels from being hidden

Tags: highcharts

See this JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/9r7vv1hm/1/
(Code Snippet at the end)

In this chart, my violet splice seems to have no label.

But in fact it has, but this label has the css property : `top:-9999px` (in addition with `position: absolute`)

I have two problem with this :

- I aim to print this chart, so labels are not an option
- My page is more than 10k px height so the label is visible somewhere else in the webpage...

Initially highchart put those label in a container with the `overflow:hidden` property (inline style), but it ofter happens that labels overflow a bit and words gets truncated, so I force overflow to be visible :

```
.report .highcharts-container {
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

My question is, how do I force every labels needed to appears around the chart ?

---

### Code Snippet:

```js
$(function() {
 // inner pie
  var catData = [
    {"name":"Field A","y":41,"v":112164,"color":"#2f7ed8"},
    {"name":"Field B","y":26,"v":72476,"color":"#0d233a"},
    {"name":"Field C","y":4,"v":11281,"color":"#8bbc21"},
    {"name":"Field D","y":0,"v":741,"color":"#910000"},
    {"name":"Field E","y":17,"v":48414,"color":"#1aadce"},
    {"name":"Field F","y":3,"v":7875,"color":"#492970"},
    {"name":"Field G","y":8,"v":21271,"color":"#f28f43"}
 ];
  // outer pie
  var typeData = [
    {"name":"Field 1","y":4,"v":11726,"color":"rgba(98,177,255,1)"},
    {"name":"Field 2","y":37,"v":100438,"color":"rgba(72,151,241,1)"},
    {"name":"Field 3","y":18,"v":49894,"color":"rgba(64,86,109,1)"},
    {"name":"Field 4","y":8,"v":22582,"color":"rgba(38,60,83,1)"},
    {"name":"Field 5","y":4,"v":11281,"color":"rgba(190,239,84,1)"},
    {"name":"Field 6","y":0,"v":0,"color":"rgba(164,213,58,1)"},
    {"name":"Field 7","y":0,"v":0,"color":"rgba(196,51,51,1)"},
    {"name":"Field 8","y":0,"v":741,"color":"rgba(170,25,25,1)"},
    {"name":"Field 9","y":4,"v":11645,"color":"rgba(77,224,255,1)"},
    {"name":"Field 10","y":13,"v":36769,"color":"rgba(51,198,231,1)"},
    {"name":"Field 11","y":0,"v":0,"color":"rgba(124,92,163,1)"},
    {"name":"Field 12","y":3,"v":7875,"color":"rgba(98,66,137,1)"},
    {"name":"Field 13","y":3,"v":8488,"color":"rgba(255,194,118,1)"},
    {"name":"Field 14","y":5,"v":12783,"color":"rgba(255,168,92,1)"}
 ];
  var series = [];
  series.push({
    name: 'Category Split',
    data: catData,
    size: '60%',
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false
    }
  });
  series.push({
    name: 'Type Split',
    data: typeData,
    size: '80%',
    innerSize: '60%',
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      color: '#808080',
      connectorColor: this.color,
      formatter: function() {
        return this.y > 0 ? '<center><b>' + this.point.name + ':</b><br> ' + this.point.v + '€ (' + Math.round(this.y) + ' %)</center>' : null;
      },
      style: {
        fontWeight: 'normal'
      },
      useHTML: true,
      distance: 50
    }
  });


  $('#Chartreport1_5').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'pie',
      plotBackgroundColor: null,
      plotBorderWidth: null,
      plotShadow: false
    },
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        borderWidth: 0,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        shadow: false
      }
    },
    series: series,
    navigation: {
      buttonOptions: {
        enabled: false
      }
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* Some labels may overflow a bit */
.report .highcharts-container {
  overflow: visible !important;
}

.report {
  height: 137.45mm;
  width: 210mm;
  padding: 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid hsl(0,50%,65%);
}

body .graphique {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid hsl(230,50%,65%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>


<div class="report"> <!-- RED BORDER -->
  <div id="Chartreport1_5" class="graphique"></div> <!-- BLUE BORDER -->
  <p>
    some legend here
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I run your example and there is 10 outer slices and 10 labels printed. Let me know which browser / width you use ?

Comment: Here : `window.screen.width = 1920`(px). I'm using Chrome Version 47.0.2526.80 m (up to date) / Windows 7

Comment: `navigator.userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36"`

Comment: Any idea ? Is it a bug from highchart or something missing in the configuration object ?

Comment: Is the issue visible after decreasing padding for labels? http://jsfiddle.net/9r7vv1hm/2/

Comment: No, there is no more problems. Is it a lack of free space available for the label ? Because data for the chart will be auto generated and I don't know how many labels will have to be displayed (Max 14)